# Adjective for the adverb "soon"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am looking for an adjective that corresponds to the adverb *soon*, to fit a sentence such as:

> That feature will be added in an *[adjective]* update.

Is there an adjective with the same meaning as *soon*?

Comment: We really do need _soonly_, don't we? If you're in marketing, go ahead and use it.

Comment: You could use "*soon-to-be-released*"

Comment: What about, in the case of, "The party is soon" ?
Isn't "soon" an adjective there?

Comment: I wouldn't class it as one. Comparing it to 'John is here' where I'd class _here_ as a locative particle, I'd call _soon_ in 'The party is soon' a temporal particle. It's analysable as a remnant of 'taking place soon', where the adverb _soon_ modifies the MWV _take place_.

Comment: Jamaican English uses "soon come" for some unspecified future arrival. Sounds perfect for new features and, especially, bug fixes.

Comment: You could use "soon-after" .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Imminent" and "impending" should suffice.

You can also say "in a jiffy" if it's gonna be real quick. *Pronto* is another good, though informal, word meaning "quick".

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forthcoming "appearing, happening, or arriving soon"

Comment: @Jimmy Why add a perfectly good answer as a comment here?

Comment: The first two are fine; the second pair are both adverbs, though.

Comment: @lly IIRC there were more comments, since deleted, that contested the word "forthcoming" in the original version of the answer, due to its other meanings as "candid" or "available".  I was merely adding some support.

Answer (score 6):

> **[Upcoming](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/upcoming)**
>   adjective
>   up·​com·​ing | \ ˈəp-ˌkə-miŋ  \
>
> **Definition of *upcoming***
>   : forthcoming, approaching
>
> [Source: Merriam-Webster Dictionary]

'Upcoming' could work for that sentence and is commonly used in this situation. M-W gives some recent examples on the Web:

> - Along with Tim, Sir Elton John and Beyoncé will also be working on the upcoming soundtrack.
>     — Victoria Rodriguez, *Seventeen*, "Everything We Know About the Live-Action "Lion King" So Far," 10 Apr. 2019
> - As royal reporter Katie Nicholl reveals in her upcoming book, Harry and Meghan: Life, Loss, and Love, Von Westenholz—a publicist for Ralph Lauren—apparently gave Harry Meghan's number.
>     — Rachel Epstein, *Marie Claire*, "Royal Reporter Katie Nicholl Details Prince Harry and Meghan Markle's Blind Date," 8 Apr. 2019

Comment: Hi Ksjdh, welcome to EL&U. This isn't a bad start, but it's too short: the system is certain to flag it as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on EL&U is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. It's best if you [edit] your answer to provide more information - e.g., add a published definition of *upcoming* (linked to the source) and say why it suits the context. For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]**. :-)

Comment: Try also forthcoming.

Comment: @Xanne What is it with this question, that answer, and people added it as a comment? >.< It's just a separate answer. =)

Comment: @Chappo I'm sure you're well-meaning, but it's a single word request and the kid gave the correct word. There's not a problem with it and you really should've upvoted it.

Comment: @Ily I'm sure you too are well-meaning. What makes you think Ksjdh is a "kid"? Why would their age permit a relaxation of our standards? There certainly ***is*** a problem with any answer that the EL&U algorithm will identify as "low quality"; and it should be obvious that upvoting low-quality answers undermines our site.

Comment: @Ily instead of lecturing me, you could have spent a few extra minutes editing the answer so that it *doesn't* get flagged as low-quality. I've done this now, and as it's a useful answer, it's now worthy of upvoting (though I should note that it falls short of a *good* answer, as it doesn't give much of an **explanation**, e.g. when would *soon* be a better choice than *upcoming*, etc). Ksjdh, please look at how I've edited your post so that you can apply a similar approach for future answers :-)

Answer (score 1):

> That feature will be added in an update coming soon.

I guess *coming soon* would be called an adjectival phrase.

Comment: Also good, but I didn't originally choose to do this because "coming soon" has sort of evolved to mean "coming eventually, or possible even never."

Answer (score -1):

I may be missing part of the question, as dialog about it seems to have been deleted, but:

- urgent
- immediate
- priority   or    high-priority
- critical

Comment: "Immediate" would work for "extremely soon" but the rest of those answers don't really have anything to do with "soon". They're synonyms of "needed" or "important".